# Find all Mongo documents for which the max value in an array matches a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given a document structure such as this:

```
{
   values: [
      { value: 10 },
      { value: 20 },
      { value: 30 }
   ]
}
```

I would like to search for all documents for which the **maximum** value in the array matches a query.

eg. If I search for all documents for which the maximum less than 25 then the example above would not match since 30 > 25.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *latest date* can you show sample document with the expected result?

Comment: Hi. I've simplified the example to make the request clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline.

If you are on version 3.2 or newer the only stage in the pipeline is the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) where you use the [`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep) and [`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) variables to return or discard documents that don't match your criteria. In the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) expression you use the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#max-aggregation) operator to return the maximum value in the "values" array return by the the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) operator because the `$redact` stage as mentioned in the documentation:

> Incorporates the functionality of [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) and [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [
            { "$lt": [ 
                { "$max": { 
                     "$map": { 
                         "input": "$values", 
                         "as": "value", 
                         "in": "$$value.value" 
                     }
                }}, 
                25
            ]}, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ]
    }}
])
```

---

From version 3.0 backward you need to first denormalize your "values" array using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your documents by `_id`; compute the maximum using `$max` and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) accumulator operator the return the array of `values`. The last stage is the `$redact` stage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$unwind": "$values" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "maxvalues": { "$max": "$values.value"}, 
        "values": { "$push": "$values" }
    }}, 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [
            { "$lt": [ "$maxvalues", 25 ] },
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ]
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for aggregates. You'll want to create a pipeline that [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)s the Date array, which will return an array of documents, one for each Date in the array.

ex:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "dates.startAt": [ date1, date2, date3] }
```

would become

```
[{"_id" : 1, "dates.startAt": date1},
 {"_id" : 1, "dates.startAt": date2},
 {"_id" : 1, "dates.startAt": date3}]
```

Combined with $max and $group (see [full list of aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions)], you should be set.